# How to use dart to remove all but digits from string using RegExp

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

Can someone show me how to use dart language to remove all but digits from a string?

Tried this but it does not seems to work

```
input.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use

```
input.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\D"), "");
```

See the [`replaceAll` method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.1/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) signature: `String replaceAll (Pattern from, String replace)`, `from` must be a [Pattern](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.1/dart-core/Pattern-class.html) class instance.

Note that `r"\D"`, a raw string literal, is a more convenient way to define regular expressions, since regular string literals, like `"\\D"`, require double escaping of backslashes that form regex escapes.

Comment: \D will remove letters, \d will remove numbers

Comment: @LidorEliyahuShelef You are right, `\D` matches any char but digits, and `\d` matches any digit.